# Minimum set of privileges needed to work on CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I've created an IAM user and intend to assign only CloudWatch access to this user. The user should be able to view and create new alarms for our ec2 instances. What is the minimum set of permissions needed for this user? Do I have to assign CloudWatchFullAccess policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do the job:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/permissions-reference-cw.html), you can read more about permissions.